# PHP : Can't change "max_file_uploads" value

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Running `php 5.5.9` in linux,

It seems like there is only **20** files upload allowed with one request in php.

I've changed that value **`max_file_uploads`** via multiple methods like,

```
php.ini :
max_file_uploads = 100

.htaccess
php_value  max_file_uploads 100

php file
ini_set('max_file_uploads', '100');
```

but none of them worked ..

I've tried settings and print the `max_file_uploads` value in php page,

```
ini_set('max_file_uploads', '100');
echo ini_get('max_file_uploads');
```

but still it displays `20`.

I've searched many pages .. but they just not working.. please help.

Comment: Is there an `=` missing in your php.ini file (it should be `max_file_uploads = 100`)?

Comment: @PhilRoss `=` is not missing in the file..

Comment: The `=` is missing in the example in your question though - you might like to update that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

Reason for the problem : Changes to the php.ini was not reflecting at server. So, contacting hosting provider, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), you can only change that value in `php.ini` or `httpd.conf`, see [`PHP_INI_SYSTEM`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

So the first should work, if 1. you are sure php is reading the ini file that you changed and 2. the other values like for example `upload_max_filesize` don't block your uploads.

And after changing the correct `php.ini` file, you also need to restart the web-server. Did you do that?

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Have you added `phpinfo();` to your page to see if the new values are present?

Comment: yes i've checked with `phpinfo()` . but it still shows default value `20`

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Make sure you are changing the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce Product Designer: 
Your PHP setting max_file_uploads is currently set to 20. We recommand to set this value at least to 100 to avoid any issue with our plugin.